# How do I stop my texture from stretching when I pose my character?

Tags: animation, texturing, uv, armature, pose-mode

[image]Quite simply, I've applied a simple image texture and matching normal map to a character and rigged him. When I pose my character (i.e. bend his knee) the texture becomes undesirably skewed and deformed. Is there a way to have the texture scale or move when the mesh deforms as to retain the quality?

Comment: It should. Can you share screenshots?

Comment: Short of procedural textures, I don't think there's much you can do, if you intend to modify the texture solely.
However, if you were to modify the way the geometry, you can get away with a hidden pipe, by making a much longer tube with a repeated iteration of the joint texture, and rigging it so that it doesn't stretch.
Fundamentally, this is a rigging/unwrapping problem, and would be best solved that way, especially if this is for export.

Answer (score 1):

In real the material on the knee would be either

- compressed when the knee is straight and normal when it is bent ... or ...
- normal when the knee is straight and stretched when the knee is bent.

If you want to "float" it out of thin air, you need to hide some extra geometry below the surface, like *pi75* mentioned in the comment above.

**Proof of concept**

[image: image "straight"]
[image: image "bent"]
[image: x-ray animation]